# Suppressing runtime exceptions in C# for ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

How do I suppress an exception in C#? I do not want to enclose it in a try-catch block with an empty `catch` block - that would defeat the purpose. I have a custom `Application_Error` handler/listener that checks for `HttpException` and I would much rather that run automatically than being prompted by Visual Studio for a `HttpException` and I would have to click Continue in the IDE.

By suppression, I mean to stop this from happening. when the `HttpException` occurs in my code, a debug exception dialog opens in Visual Studio and my project pauses. Then when I click Continue my `Application_Error` is able to handle it. I would like it to automatically continue.

In response to Simon's answer, I do not want exception handling turned off globally.

Comment: Sorry if I've missed something, but what do you mean by "suppress" an exception if you don't mean an empty try-catch? Are you looking for a debug solution, release, or both? Is this a temporary measure or permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two Things:**

1. For production: Use [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/). Use ELMAH and any Yellow Screen of Death errors get logged.
2. For Development and YSOD: See this Stack Overflow question that covers your specific issue:

> [Catching Exceptions within ASPX and ASCX Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138071/catching-exceptions-within-aspx-and-ascx-pages/138084)

Comment: That does not answer my question. I am using Application_Error to catch my 404 and it does *not* show a yellow screen of death.

Comment: No, but if you have an unhandled exception, ELMAH Will log all of them, even if they are surpressed from the end user.

Answer (score 0):

You can change which exceptions cause the IDE to break by going to Debug -> Exceptions and turn off the Thrown and User-unhandled options for the relevant exceptions.

Comment: I do not want to turn this off globally.