# catch exceptions from all Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am trying to log all "general errors" from the site I am maintaining, to debug the code-behind, without having to show the detailed error page to the users. The `web.config` says:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/GeneralError.html"/>
```

which works for problems like divide by zero, null-reference exceptions, missing dll, etc. After lots of reading here I found that these are the "unhandled exceptions", but do not reach the handler `Application_Error()` in `global.asax`. What does work, on a per-page basis, is:

```
protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
{
    Exception TheException = Server.GetLastError();
    // todo: log the exception to the database
    base.OnError(e); //pass the exception to the regular handler
    return;
}
```

But could this be changed to log the unhandled exceptions of all pages with a single method? How can I overwrite, or modify, the base class `Page`?

I also thought of put logging in the code-behind of `GeneralError.aspx`, but then there would be no stack trace or exception message, and also any user may call this page directly just to annoy us.

I investigated using some `IErrorHandler` interface mentioned in some posts, but this should relate to WinForm apps, not to asp.net web apps.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Application_Error method in your Global.asax file.

Inside your Application_Error method implementation call Server.GetLastError(), log the details of the exception returned by Server.GetLastError().

```
Exception LastError;
String ErrMessage;

LastError = Server.GetLastError();

if (LastError != null)
   ErrMessage = LastError.Message;
else
   ErrMessage = "No Errors";

Response.Write("Last Error = " + ErrMessage);
```

See here at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror(v=vs.110).aspx) or if you want a **complete Microsoft Example at [Complete Example for Error Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417(v=vs.100).aspx)**.

Comment: I looked into this, but the Application_Error handler is NOT called in case of a simple unhandled exception on a page. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16348903/1845672

Comment: Which one? Within a normal ASP.Net Application the Application_Error within the Global.asax class should catch the errors.

Comment: No, it should catch all UNHANDLED exceptions. The "unhandled" exceptions I am after will be handled somewhere, that's how the GeneralError page is shown. An exception that is truly unhandled will bring down the IIS server, and only such exceptions are seen in the Global.asax handler. I tested that my humble page exception is seen by the OnError on the page, but not in Global.asax.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class:

```
public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
     {
         Exception TheException = Server.GetLastError();
         // todo: log the exception to the database
         base.OnError(e); //pass the exception to the regular handler
         return;
     }
}
```

and instead of inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page inherit from MyPage on your individual pages.

Comment: This would mean to change the base class name in all 100+ pages of our site, and to be careful when creating new pages. I was hoping for some single declaration like `Page.OnError += mynewhandler` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently studying https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479332.aspx, found through https://stackoverflow.com/a/138088/1845672 which talks about exactly my problem with the exact same approach: provide a solution to log errors on all pages in a maintainable way without modifying all pages.

The download link on the microsoft site is stale. According to: https://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=64 the sources are moved from the microsoft site to: elmah.googlecode.com/files/GDN-ELMAH-1.0.5527-setup.zip .

Looks like this is a complete solution . . .